# Error in date conversion when I use join

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, type-conversion

Here is my query which works well:

```
select convert(date,convert(varchar,dd.effdate),111)  kk       
from INS_VW_Return  dd  --join  MS_Account qq    on (dd.accountno ='0'+qq.Class_Account)
 where dd.accountno in (select '0'+t.Class_Account 
                       from INS_Insurance_Status t 
                       where t.Insurance_Status=0
                       )
 and  dd.importdate = cast(getdate() as date)
 and dd.effdate<= cast(convert(VARCHAR(10),getdate(),112) as int)
```

But the thing is if I uncomment `MS_Account` the query will return following error:

```
Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
```

If I remove convert function and put a field (like dd.effdate) or comment out MS_Account again it will work with no error.

I don't know why it happens because as you can see there is nothing related to that table in select statement and conversion process. I need to mention that count(*) for both queries are same.

You can see some info via following links:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6O9rKqbTANzVWJSbHVRWnRlVUk

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6O9rKqbTANzLUV2QTlUODlkZ0U/view

Comment: Could you share the tables schema and some sample data which reproduce the problem?

Comment: You can take a look at the result of queries using this link:    https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6O9rKqbTANzLUV2QTlUODlkZ0U

Comment: I wish I could help you with this information, but I am afraid I can't. If you have some time, and since you are new to SO (welcome!), take a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: What is `INS_VW_Return`? Is it a `VIEW`? SQL Server is well known for executing things in an unexpected order. SQL is not a language, where you tell the engine *Do this, and than do this, after this do...* It is rather a *This is what I want, do what ever is needed*-language. Quite probably there is a place in your query **where you think this is executed *after* a conversion** but it isn't. Please provide more details.

Comment: What is the datatype of dd.effdate? Is it an INT representation of a date with no punctuation?

Comment: I have uploaded two files for more information, the links are presented with above post. dd.effdate is char(8) column to keep date as YYYYMMDD format.

Answer (score 0):

Your join is most likely adding null records in the date field.  Add a null handler to the select query to provide a date when the date is null due to the join.

Comment: I'm afraid it's not the problem there is null here. You can see the queries result in following link:      https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6O9rKqbTANzLUV2QTlUODlkZ0U

Comment: It sounds like SQL-Server bug to me more than user mistake.